# Passar duas variáveis na url em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eu tenho um website que possui 5 idiomas diferentes e ao escolher um idioma o texto da página muda! Pra isso eu fiz uma função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
    var thelang = document.getElementById('lang').options[document.getElementById('lang').selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname +'?lang=' + thelang;
}
</script><br/>
```

O problema é que agora eu tenho dois `id` diferentes para essa página, e gostava de saber como integro nessa função também o `id`.

Por exemplo o url deveria ficar mais ou menos assim:
`localhost:8080/.../index.php?id=1&&lang=pt`, mas como não consegui passar o `id`para a varíavel, agora as páginas deixaram de traduzir. O `id` eu busco via `GET`

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$id);
    $query="SELECT * FROM local where local_id='".$id."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        if ($row['local_id'] == 1)
        {
            ?> //AQUI FICA O HTML <?php } ?>
```

Os idiomas são escolhidos através de um select, o que está a acontecer é que já não dá mais para carregar, só consigo atualizar a página manualmente, mudando no URL...

Comment: Esse ID está onde? no DOM ou no servidor?

Comment: Está no servidor!

Comment: Quando escolhes o idioma, o url perde o id, é isso?

Comment: Olá @Leite!!! Neste caso nem dá para escolher o idioma, simplesmente quando vou escolher um não acontece nada, só consigo mudar manualmente

Comment: Olá! Qual é o url que tens antes de escolher um idioma e como fica depois de escolheres (confirma se muda ou nao)

Comment: Antes de escolher o idioma tenho assim `http://localhost:8080/hoteljupiter/index.php?id=2` , depois para escolher a página fica toda em branco, mas agora tentei na minha função assim `window.location.href = window.location.pathname +'?id=' + id +'&lang=' + thelang;` , a página agora ao carregar num idioma já não fica em branco, só nao acontece nada, só se mudar o idioma manualmente que está no URL

Comment: @Leite agora é que li melhor a tua pergunta, o link depois de escolher o idioma, o id desaparece sim sem fazer aquela alteração na minha função, peço desculpa

Comment: Sim, era esse o problema original. Mas com esta alteração que fizeste o url deve ficar `?id=undefined&lang=pt`, isso? Como fica o url? Nem muda a página?

Comment: O url não muda mais com essa alteração se eu escolher um dos idiomas, simplesmente já não acontece nada!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78926/discussion-between-leite-and-ana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa esta função de ajuda para adicionar/alterar valores da querystring.

Tentei comentar para perceberes o que está a acontecer em cada passo, mas se tiveres dúvidas, estás a vontade para perguntar.

```
function updateQuerystring(whatKey, newValue) {
    var exists = false; // vamos usar para ver se a chave já existe na querystring
    var qs = []; // a futura querystring (é um array, mas vamos tornar num string no fim)
    var __qs = window.location.search || ""; // a querystring actual ou uma string vazia, já deve ser caso nao exista, mas só para o caso..
    var _qs = __qs.substring(1).split("&"); // substring(1) remove o "?" do inicio e split("&") transforma num array, separando a string nos "&"

    for (var idx in _qs) { // por cada combinacao "chave=valor" na querystring
        var _kv = _qs[idx].split("="); // _qs[idx] é algo tipo "chave=valor" entao usamos split("=") para separar novamente
        var _key = _kv[0]; // 0 = chave
        var _value = _kv[1]; // 1 = valor

        if (_key === whatKey) { // se a _key for a que queremos alterar (a que foi passada a esta funcao), alteramos entao o valor
            _value = newValue;
            exists = true;
        }

        // metemos no tal novo array pra querystring, se for encontrado no if acima, entao _value vai ser o novo valor
        qs.push(_key + "=" + _value); // 
    }

    if (!exists) { // se nao encontramos durante o ciclo acima, entao adicionamos uma nova com os valores passados
        qs.push(whatKey + "=" + newValue);
    }

    // aqui retornamos (duh :P)
    return "?" + qs.join("&"); // juntamos o novo array com '&' e ficamos com uma string que podemos usar como querystring
}
```

Depois na tua função, podes chamar esta e pedir para actualizar o parâmetro `lang` com o que recebeste do `<select>`

```
function submitForm() {
    var thelang = var thelang = document.getElementById('lang').options[document.getElementById('lang').selectedIndex].value;
    var newquerystring = updateQuerystring("lang", thelang);
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + newquerystring;
}
```

Comment: Agradeço imenso! Está a funcionar perfeitamente